# Curly brace cannot be escaped in ValueData section in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to use  a constant in the `ValueData` section of Inno Setup `[Registry]` section.

My constant looks like this:

```
#define TConst "abcd {efgh}"
```

The useage in the `[Registry]` section:

```
ValueData: "{#TConst}"
```

But I am getting the error like:

> Unknown constant, kindly use 2 consecutive `{` characters

Comment: `{` and `}` are special characters. You need to show your script for us to help you. If it is a constant, then most likely you need a `#`, eg: `abcd {#efgh}` but we need to see the script and the definition of the constant really.

Comment: I just have this constant at the top of my iss file and I am simply using it in the [Registry] section ValueData to set a registry value for e.g #define TConst "abcd {efgh}" and then in the ValueData section ValueData: "{#TConst}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you mentioned is related to this bit of your script: `{efgh}`. As mentioned in the comments, `{` and `}` are special characters. Look here for more information about [constants](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_consts.htm). Towards the top of the article it states:

> A "{" character is treated as the start of the constant. If you want to use that actual character in a place where constants are supported, you must use two consecutive "{" characters. (You do not need to double "}" characters.)

If your **constant** is actually:

```
#define TConst "abcd {efgh}"
```

Then this implies that you want to **see** the curly braces, then you need to double the first one up:

```
#define TConst "abcd {{efgh}"
```

Now the parser will not get confused when compiling the setup.

Comment: @angelo.mastro my answer says that!